# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: command, discord, discord.js, bots

I tried to create a command of -clear (amount) and the coomand doing well but the permissions dont
this is what the error i get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\main.js:448:23)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\elyas\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

and here the code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    const deltef = args[1]
    const amount = parseInt(args[1]);
    if(message.member.roles.cache.has('715841880482512897')) {
        if(args[0] == 'clear') {
            if (isNaN(amount)) {
                 message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
            } else if (amount < 2 || amount > 100) {
                 message.reply('you need to input a number between 2 and 100.');
            }  
            else if (amount > 2 || amount < 100)
                message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
                message.channel.send("deleted" + " " + deltef + " " + "messages" + ('✅'))
            }
    }  
}
    
);
```

if you can help i will be happy

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use this command in DM's? Because according to the Discord.JS documentation `message.member` is only available in guilds, what means if you try to use it in DM's it will be `undefined`.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=member

I recommend limiting commanmd usage only to guilds so things like this can't happen.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
  // your code...
})
```

Comment: but now everyone can use the command i need that only the man who have the specific role can do it

Comment: The most important thing is that the error is fixed. If you want to limit it to only users who have a specific role you can still do that with something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6w4u9mcn/4/) (code above may need changes depending on how you want to use it exactly)